# PHP Random 0 is being placed

Tags: php

I have created a PHP script that will take images from a Flickr account and then display them in album form. Everything is working fine except for this pesky little 0 that occurs before each album . Here is a sample HTML document:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="chrome-extension://bfbmjmiodbnnpllbbbfblcplfjjepjdn/js/injected.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css"></style>
</head>

<body>0
    <div class="album" id="72157643471292484">
        <img class="album-thumnail" src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3702/13647757594_46fb10ca56_m.jpg">
        <div class="album-information">
            <div class="album-header">
                <p class="album-title">Set 1</p><span class="album-contents">3</span>
            </div>
            <p class="album-description"></p>
        </div>
    </div>0
    <div class="album" id="72157643469056814">
        <img class="album-thumnail" src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3739/13647432073_9c11d27b7c_m.jpg">
        <div class="album-information">
            <div class="album-header">
                <p class="album-title">Test Gallery 1</p><span class="album-contents">9</span>
            </div>
            <p class="album-description">Bing Backgrounds</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

In the above code, after the  tag and lower once the  is closed, there is a second 0. They come before the opening tag of the albums and I have no idea why. I don't think I've mentioned how this is called yet, but it is called via jQuery's AJAX.

Here is the PHP

```
<?php

$api = '';
$userid = '';
$apiurl = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?';
$responseformat = 'php_serial';

//Initiate the PHP script
echo createHTML();


function createHTML(){
    return '<div class="gallery">'.createCollectionHTML().'</div>';
}

function createCollectionHTML(){
    $html_resp = '';
    $collections = getCollections();
    foreach($collections['collections']['collection'] as $c){
        $html_resp = $html_resp.'
        <div class="collection">
        <div class="coll-header">
            <div class="text-header"><span>'.$c['title'].'</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="coll-albums">'.getAlbumHTML($c).'</div></div>';
    }
    return $html_resp;
}

function getAlbumHTML($coll_data){
    $album_html = "";
    $album_num = 0;
    foreach($coll_data['set']as $s){
        $album_num++;
        $album_html_lower = '<div id="'.$s['id'].'"><img class="album-thumnail" src="'.getSetThumbnailURL($s['id']).'"/><div class="album-information"><div class="album-header"><p class="album-title">'.$s['title'].'</p><span class="album-contents">'.getSetContentsNum($s['id']).'</span></div><p class="album-description">'.$s['description'].'</p></div></div>';
        if($album_num == 1){
            $album_html = $album_html + '<div class="album-row">'.$album_html_lower;
        }else if($album_num == 2){
            $album_html = $album_html + $album_html_lower;
        }else if($album_nnum == 3){
            $album_html = $album_html + $album_html_lower.'</div>';
            $album_num = 0;
        }
    }
    return $album_html;
}

function getSetContentsNum($id){
    $set_data = getSetInformation($id);
    return $set_data['photoset']['count_photos'];
}
function getRequest($arguments){
        global $apiurl;

    //Enocdes the arguments for JSON request
    $encoded_params = array();
    foreach ($arguments as $k => $v){
        $encoded_params[] = urlencode($k).'='.urlencode($v);
    }

    //Join the url via arguments and $apiurl variable
    $url = $apiurl.implode('&', $encoded_params);

    //Request the file, unserialize the JSON response
    $rsp = file_get_contents($url);
    $rsp_obj = unserialize($rsp);

    //Checks if response was okay, else, returns failure message
    if($rsp_obj['stat']== 'ok'){
        return $rsp_obj;
    }else{
        echo 'requestfail|message:'.$rsp_obj['message'];
        return;
    }
}

function getCollections(){
    global $api;
    global $userid;
    global $responseformat;   

    $args = array(
        'method' => 'flickr.collections.getTree',
        'api_key' => $api,
        'user_id' => $userid,
        'format' => $responseformat
        );
       return getRequest($args);
}

function getSetInformation($id){
        global $api;
    global $userid;
    global $responseformat; 

    $args = array(
        'method' => 'flickr.photosets.getInfo',
        'photoset_id' => $id,
            'api_key' => $api,
    'format' => $responseformat
        );
       return getRequest($args);
}

function getSetPhotos($id){
        global $api;
    global $userid;
    global $responseformat; 
        $args = array(
        'method' => 'flickr.photosets.getPhotos',
        'photoset_id' => $id,
        'extras' => 'url_s',
        'media' => 'photos',
            'api_key' => $api,
    'format' => $responseformat
        );
       return getRequest($args);
}

function getSetThumbnail($id){
    $set_pics = getSetPHotos($id);
    return $set_pics['photoset']['photo'][0];
}

function getSetThumbnailURL($id){
    $thumbnail_info = getSetThumbnail($id);
    return $thumbnail_info['url_s'];
}
?>
```

I think it would be also worthy to note that if I place a "1" in the $album_html variable or place a 1 before the opening tag of the $album_html_lower, the 0 is replaced in either case by the 1, however, I can not completely remove the 0. So how do I remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're concatenating strings using the plus sign, instead of using a dot:

```
// Wrong
$album_html = $album_html + $album_html_lower;
// Right
$album_html = $album_html . $album_html_lower;
```

The plus sign is only used in arithmetic operations, which makes PHP want to cast the variables to integers. Strings that do not start with integers are cast to 0, thus resulting in the HTML you gave. Replace the plus signs with a dot and the problem is solved.

You could also replace those statements with the shorthand notation:

```
$album_html .= $album_html_lower;
```

The `.=` operator concatenates the right hand value to the end of the left hand value.

On a side note, the third if-statement in `getAlbumHTML()` contains an 'n' too much in the variable name `$album_nnum`.